# Error from URLpatterns

Tags: python, angularjs, django, django-models, django-views

I have a project which is giving me the following error:

> File "path-to-environment\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls__init__.py",
>   line 99, in url
>      urlconf_module, app_name, namespace = view
>      ValueError: too many values to unpack(expected 3)

The code its emanating from is from my url.py with this code:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'videos', views.VideosViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^api/', router.urls),
]
```

After some research, I understand why such an error might come up, but in this context i cant seem to figure out whats wrong with my code that's causing this error. I'm new to Django and i am using a tutorial on how to get Django to work with Angular via Django Rest Framework.

Comment: Which version of Django do you use? Make sure that you use the version which is specified in your tutorial because the latest Django supports both 2 and 3 arguments for the case. Source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/ecb59cc6579402b68ddfd4499bf30edacf5963be/django/conf/urls/__init__.py#L32

Comment: okay thank you, i gues i am using a different version because it does not have provision for two

Comment: @viach if i want to use 3 arguements, what then would i have to add?

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
from django.conf.urls import include
...
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
...
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/#including-other-urlconfs